# Class constructor and unit tests

Tags: c#

I have created a class `Account`that has the common fields for the account. It looks likes this:

```
    public class Account
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Balance { get; set; }

        public Account(double Credit)
        {
            Balance = Credit;
        }
     }
```

Then I created a `Withdrawal` class where the withdrawal take place. This `withdrawal` class inherits from the `Account` Class. I have created an interface where the `withdrawal` class inherits from. The main reason for having a constructor in the account class is, when a customer first opens an account with the bank, an amount must be credited into the customer's  account as a form of thank you for opening an account with us. This amount is not fixed, it depends on the type of account that the customer opens.

My challenge now is anytime I am executing the withdrawal class, the constructor of the base class gets executed and the thank you gift replaces any amount the customer has in the balance.

What I really want to do is for the constructor to get executed pmce and the `withdrawal` class should work without the base class constructor firing up.

I will also like to know if I have violated any SOLID principle, especially in the logic method . Will I be able to unit test `withdrawal1` method most especially.

This is my `Withdrawal` class

```
    public class Withdrawal : Account, IAccountWithdrawal
    {
        public Withdrawal() : base(400)
        {
        }

        public void Withdrawal1(double Amount)
        {
            bool Result = Logic(Amount);
        }

        public bool Logic (double Amt)
        {
            if (Amt <= Balance)
            {
                Balance -= Amt;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An object should encapsulate its own data and operations that work on this data **only**.

So the `Account` class should hold the `Balance` as data. As noted above, use `decimal` for financial calculations. It should also hide the balance from any outside manipulation that does not go through the appropriate methods, so it should be `private`. One could envision two methods that change the balance: `Withdraw` and `Deposit`. Because the Balance is private, we will also need a `GetCurrentBalance` method to read the current balance. The constructor takes all parameters that are required to create a valid new account (note that `Balance` will default to 0).

```
public class Account {

   public Account(string name) {
       Name = name;
   }

   // Name is required for a valid account, so it is part of the constructor
   public string Name { get; private set; }

   // Balance is critical, so it is private to prevent direct manipulation from outside
   private decimal Balance { get; set; }

   public decimal GetCurrentBalance() {
       return Balance;
   }

   public void Deposit(decimal amount) {
       Balance += amount;
       // here would be a good place to write audit logs ...
   }

   public void Withdraw(decimal amount) {
       if (Balance < amount) {
           throw new InvalidOperationException($"The account '{Name}' can not be overdrawn.")
       }
       Balance -= amount;
   }
}
```

But for many use cases, there will be more than one object involved. Let us look at the "Create new account and deposit the initial gift" use case. There are actually two accounts involved: the account to be created and the account of the bank from which the gift should be transferred.

In such cases where more than one object is involved, it is better to have a separate `DomainService` class that handles the business logic. This makes the code easier to understand because there are no hidden calls between the involved objects. The DomainService provides a specific method for every business case, and takes all involved objects as parameters. In our example, there is an explicit `OpenNewAccount` method that creates the new account and transfers the initial gift. Note that the AccountDomainService does not care how the required `accountToWithdrawGift` is to be retrieved, it just takes it as parameter. Also note that because we know the exact use case, we can generate meaningful error messages.

```
public AccountDomainService {

   public Account OpenNewAccount(string name, Account accountToWithdrawGift, decimal giftAmount) {

      // create the new Account
      var newAccount = new Account(name);

      // now handle the gift
      try {
         accountToWithdrawGift.Withdraw(giftAmount);
         newAccount.Deposit(giftAmount);
      }
      catch (InvalidOperationException ex) {
          throw new InvalidOperationException (
              $"The account '{accountToWithdrawGift.Name}' has insufficient balance " +                 
              $"to withdraw the gift amount '{giftAmount}'.", ex
          );
      }

      return newAccount;
   }
}
```

The business logic is called by an `ApplicationService` which faces the outside (e.g. UI, webservice). Here is a good place to validate any user inputs and handle database access.

```
public class AccountApplicationService {

     private DbContext _dbContext;
     private AccountDomainService _domainService;

     // you can use Dependency Injection to provide the appropiate dbContext and domainService
     public AccountApplicationService(DbContext dbContext, AccountDomainService domainService) {
         _dbContext = dbContext;
         _domainService = domainService;
     }

     public Account OpenNewAccount(OpenNewAccountCommand command) {

         // validate user input ...
         Validate(command);

         // load bank account from the database
         var accountToWithdrawGift = _dbContext.Accounts.Single(a => a.Name == "Bank Ldt.");
         const decimal giftAmount = 400.00M;

         // call domain service to execute the business case
         var newAccount = _domainService.OpenNewAccount(command.Name, accountToWithdrawGift, giftAmount);

         // persist new Account in the Database
         _dbContext.Accounts.Add(newAccount);
         _dbContext.SaveChanges();

         return newAccount;
     }
}
```

With this structure, the business logic encapsulated in `Account` and `AccountDomainService` can be unit tested in full without the need to mock the database. The database required by `AccountApplicationService` can be mocked and injected in the constructor.

Comment: wow. Your code is clean and understandable. It was well architected. I was so green with envy. I will really want to make you a mentor, if you dont mind pls.